# Applying filter/reduce to dictionary makes Swift compiler crash: my mistake or bug?

Tags: swift, dictionary, functional-programming, swift2, reduce

I would like to obtain the maximum of all those values in a dictionary whose keys are distinct from a specified one, and do so in a functional manner. Here is an approximation of my code:

```
let d = [1:2, 2:3, 3:4]
let x = d.filter() { (key, _) in key != 1 }
let y = x.map() { (key, value) in value }
let z = y.reduce(0) { (max, value) in max(value, max) }
assert(z == 4)
```

Unfortunately the line that calculates `z` makes the Swift compiler (from the latest Xcode 7 beta) crash in its `CanTypeVisitor`.

Am I committing an (obvious) mistake in applying `filter`/`reduce` like this (and is there perhaps a more concise functional form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was apparently related to the double use of `max`. If I replace the offending line by this one, the compiler won't crash:

```
let z = y.reduce(0) { (max, value) in (value > max) ? value : max }
```